# GCP MIG instance in repair

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have MIG base on an instance template with autoscale on a custom metric
with 1 instance running and goes up when needed + load balancer

My App needs to be live all the time
sometimes I get an error and when I check I saw there is only 1 instance in the group and it's in repair ( after ~2 min it back to be live )
the health check will not help me as my boot time for the app is a little bit long

is there a way to config the MIG so it will not pot the only instance to repair? ( lunch new one before )
is there a way to disable this at all?
or notify me?

Thanks

Comment: What 'repair' are you referring to? Is it autohealing? https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/autohealing-instances-in-migs

Comment: Hi 
no, it's not auto-healing as I didn't configure that   
I have my app running and I got an error from the app that something not working 
I open the GCP console I can see the instance with the icon changing and when I hover on it its says repair 
I think its something related to GCP local maintenance and that's ok I just want to have another one on before they start the repair 
if that even possible